# Rails - Sort by a condition and limit?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sql-order-by

I am trying to fetch only 5 records from a table, and I need to ensure that the sort order is in a way that a specific record will always be at position 0.

How do I achieve this? My DB is MYSql

```
User.order("IF(id == #{current_user.id}) DESC").take(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a way to do this natively with SQL/MySQL, but I'd simply call two queries:

```
users = User.where.not(id: current_user.id).take(4) # perform order/etc
users.unshift(current_user)                         # or find specific record
```

Comment: Couldn't find a way to do this through sql, ended up doing something similar to this. Thanks